# "this.parentNode.parentNode" is undefined in firefox but works in other browsers

Tags: javascript

In the code below, the `alert` shows the correct data-table value in Google Chrome but is undefined in Mozilla Firefox - is there something I am missing?

```html
<td>
<a onclick="add_data_event(this.parentNode.parentNode, '<?=$result['g_id'];?>')" 
   class="btn btn-primary" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#addremindermodel-editclick">
       <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
</td>

<script>
    function add_data_event(index, ser)
    {
        alert('I am in script');
        alert(index.cells[1].innerText);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the parentNode property is working in my firefox version 36.0.4. What version is yours ?

Comment: Works if there are enough cells: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/qv6zrme1/ and a TR of course.

Comment: The mozilla firefox doesn't support 'innerText' so inspite of the using textContent is a better option